# Click on image and the name of the image shows up in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a 4 different image of Mozart, and when a particular image is clicked, the name of the picture will show at the bottom. Not sure how to begin this in jquery.

HTML:

```
 <a class="art" href=""><img src="mozart.jpg"></a>
```

CSS:

```
 .art {
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJFpG/9/)

---

Here's an example of a  quick way to do it::

**jQuery:**

```
$('img').click(function(){
    if($(this).next('p').text().length == 0) {
       $(this).next('p').text($(this).attr('src'));
    }
    else {
       $(this).next('p').text('');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="mozart.jpg">  <p></p>
<img src="mozart2.jpg"> <p></p>
<img src="mozart3.jpg"> <p></p>
<img src="mozart4.jpg"> <p></p>
```

Comment: My mistake, didn't get the updated one. Let me plug this in and see. Also, how can I have it just default on the first image with name?